# Scene order: is this order of scenes confusing?

Tags: planning, scene

Okay so say is my story scene order is in this order in the book. Future scene (insight) --> past scene (flashback) --> present day.

What do you think? Will this order be confusing for my readers?

Answer (score 1):

IT will be confusing for some people. But are you going to use indicators to set them apart or just let them figure it out? Also, is that scene order going to be same throughout the entire story or are you just going to keep it that way for a few chapters?

Eventually, if the readers really want to understand the book, they'll read rest of it and wouldn't be confused after the first 5 or so chapters.

I have read a couple of stories that used your order before and it is usually confusing and frustrating at first when I'm trying to understand who the characters are, when a certain event happen and if it makes sense.

Personally, if your story is interesting, it'll grasp your reader's attention and prone them to want to know what transpires in your story even if the order goes from future to present. It will be like a challenge to them.

Answer (score 0):

Put time-stamps at the beginning of each chapter, or time switch, and you should be okay. I'm not sure how you would indicate "present day" if your book starts "in the future," but that's up to you.